# Adding rounded corners (border-radius) to a Facebook embedded stream?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

Here's my HTML to embed a facebook page

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/BLANK/" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="500" data-height="300" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="true" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/BLANK/" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/BLANK/">BLANK</a></blockquote></div>
```

And here's my JS to embed it

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.12';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

How can I make the corners rounded?...do I add CSS?...is there a "data-XXX" to add somewhere?

Comment: You’ll have to target the iframe element that gets dynamically inserted into this.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook loads the page as an `iframe`, and the grey border around it is within the `iframe` element. It's not possible to edit the contents of an iframe from the parent page, so unfortunately you won't be able to round those borders.

To clarify, in normal scenarious, `border-radius: 10px` is the CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

You add rounded corners by using CSS:

```
#element {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I know how to do border-radius...the question was specific to Facebook.

Comment: Wouldn't adding rounded corners to the parent container accomplish what you asked?

Comment: If it was that easy, I wouldn't have asked ;-)
I've gone through every element in the inspector and nothing does it, so I'm hoping there's a combination that I didn't notice or think of to get it done.